# Y-scale issue in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, bar-chart, axis

I am trying to plot the following data frame called part2 with ggplot 2. This is a sample of my data:

```
Month Denial.Code freq
1    January       Total    0
2   February       Total  626
3      March       Total 1151
4      April       Total  849
5        May       Total 1144
6       June       Total  957
7       July       Total  911
8     August       Total 1145
9  September       Total  902
10   October       Total 1211
11  November       Total  920
12  December       Total  948

ggplot(part2, aes (x = Month,y=freq, fill = 
      factor(Denial.Code)))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+xlab("")
      +ylab("Denial Frequency")+scale_fill_discrete(name="Denial Code")
      +ggtitle("# Denials by Month")
```

However my y-scale is extremely jumbled up for some reason. The y-scale plot goes from 0 -> 1211 fine, and then jumps to 626. I think it was following an old factor order when the months were presented in Alphabetical order, but I don't know how to fix it.

Picture is below:

[image]

Comment: Is your `freq` variable a numeric one?

Comment: Yeah that was the issue - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem, so I'm guessing at some point through out your process you change your variables' type and you don't have a numeric `freq` variable.

This is what I've tried:

```
part2 = read.table(text=
"Month Denial.Code freq
1    January       Total    0
2   February       Total  626
3      March       Total 1151
4      April       Total  849
5        May       Total 1144
6       June       Total  957
7       July       Total  911
8     August       Total 1145
9  September       Total  902
10   October       Total 1211
11  November       Total  920
12  December       Total  948", header=T)

library(ggplot2)

# re-order the level of variable to be plotted in the right order
part2$Month = factor(part2$Month, c("January","February","March","April","May",
                        "June","July","August","September","October",
                        "November","December"))

ggplot(part2, aes (x = Month,y=freq, fill = factor(Denial.Code)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  xlab("") +ylab("Denial Frequency")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Denial Code")+
  ggtitle("# Denials by Month")
```

and I get:

[image]

Comment: I had realized my freq variable was a factor of strings and not numeric, so it all worked out! And I got identical results. Thanks so much!