# ggplot: why is the y-scale larger than the actual values for each response?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Likely a dumb question, but I cannot seem to find a solution: I am trying to graph a categorical variable on the x-axis (3 groups) and a continuous variable (% of 0 - 100) on the y-axis. When I do so, I have to clarify that the geom_bar is stat = "identity" or use the geom_col.

However, the values still show up at 4000 on the y-axis, even after following the comments from [Y-scale issue in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935093/y-scale-issue-in-ggplot) and from [Why is the value of y bar larger than the actual range of y in stacked bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363878/why-is-the-value-of-y-bar-larger-than-the-actual-range-of-y-in-stacked-bar-plot).

Here is how the graph keeps coming out:

[image]

I also double checked that the x variable is a factor and the y variable is numeric. Why would this still be coming out at 4000 instead of 100, like a percentage?

EDIT:
The y-values are simply responses from participants. I have a large dataset (N = 600) and the y-value are a percentage from 0-100 given by each participant. So, in each group (N = 200 per group), I have a value for the percentage. I wanted to visually compare the three groups based on the percentages they gave.

This is the code I used to plot the graph.

```
df$group <- as.factor(df$group)
df$confid<- as.numeric(df$confid)

library(ggplot2)                
plot <-ggplot(df, aes(group, confid))+
  geom_col()+ 
  ylab("confid %") + 
  xlab("group")
```

Comment: You should divide the numbers by 100. For example, 0.1 is equal to 10%.

Comment: Hi Afton, please share your data and your code so that we can create the same plot you posted.

Comment: Obviously, the problem is the computation of the y-values, but you do not convey the information how you compute them (with *table*?). Please post the code how you compute them.

Comment: @Edo Hi, I have added more information and the code I used to write the graph. I hope this is helpful in finding a solution! I honestly think I am overlooking something simple but cannot yet figure it out.

Comment: @cdalitz Edit added to the post!! I hope this provides more information to find a solution.

Comment: Please provide a mock of your data. I think in your graph you are summing together all the "confid". How are you thinking to summarise your 200 rows in one? an average? Why do you want to plot a barchart? Shouldn't you plot 3 histograms to see the distribution of the response per each group?

Comment: `library(dplyr);library(ggplot2);df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(confid = mean(confid)) %>% ggplot() + geom_col(aes(group, confid))` should be what you're looking for if I understood your problem and your data.

Comment: However, consider also doing this: `library(ggplot2);ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x = confid, fill = group), alpha = 0.4)`

Comment: What does the builtin function *barplot* yield? `barplot(height=df$confid, names.arg=df$group)`

Comment: It certainly seems like you are interested in the *average* value given (perhaps with confidence intervals) for each group, rather than the sum of each group (which is what you have now). In this case, @Allan-Cameron  provided a response which should get you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps trying to plot the *mean* percentage in each group? Otherwise, it is not clear how a bar plot could easily represent what you are looking for. You could perhaps add error bars to give an idea of the spread of responses.

Suppose your data looks like this:

```r
set.seed(4)

df <- data.frame(group = factor(rep(1:3, each = 200)),
                 confid = sample(40, 600, TRUE))
```

Using your plotting code, we get very similar results to yours:

```r
library(ggplot2)                
plot <-ggplot(df, aes(group, confid))+
  geom_col()+ 
  ylab("confid %") + 
  xlab("group")

plot
```

[image]

However, if we use `stat_summary`, we can instead plot the mean and standard error for each group:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(group, confid)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, width = 0.6, 
               fill = "deepskyblue", color = "gray50") +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(stat = "summary") +
  ylab("confid %") + 
  xlab("group")
```

[image]